# Qt - How to find children right

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to find a widget that I added to the screen and do some manipulations with it, but the list of children is empty every time. What am I doing wrong?
Here is the code (to run it, create a new clean project and replace the text in MainWindow.cpp):

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QList>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
, ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QLabel* wid = new QLabel("hello");
    ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(wid);
    QList<QLabel*> list = ui->centralWidget->findChildren<QLabel*>();
    qDebug() << list.isEmpty();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: You made the widget a child of the layout not  `ui->centralWidget`

Comment: @drescherjm That is, with layouts this does not work out?

Comment: Although looking at the documentation, the default parameter is to do a recursive find. I would expect the layout to be a child of `ui->centralWidget` not sure why that fails.

Comment: @drescherjm If I write `QList<QLabel*> list = ui->centralWidget->layout()->findChildren<QLabel*>();`, this also do not work

Comment: Maybe addWidget() does not make it a child of the layout. I thought that it did. You can use the parent parameter of the constructor to fix this. I mean `QLabel* wid = new QLabel("hello", ui->centralWidget);` should make the original example work.

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah, thank you, it's work now!